# How to correctly display data from a websocket

Tags: reactjs

I have a database with orders. I receive a list of all orders from a websocket. When adding a new order to the database, I send it to the client. There this order needs to be displayed at the beginning of the page. In the future there may be a lot of orders, and of course I filter them. But still, there can also be many of them. As far as I understand, application state is not very suitable for storing such information. Please tell me how to implement this most effectively.

So far my terrible code looks like this:

```
class P2PSell extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            message: "",
            stompClient: null,
            orders: []
        }
    }
    
    setOrders = (orders) => {
        this.setState({
            orders: JSON.parse(orders)
        })
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        
        const connectToWebSocket = () => {
            const socket = new SockJS('http://localhost:8080/ws');
            const client = Stomp.over(socket);
            const root = ReactDom.createRoot(document.getElementById('orders-list'));
            let elements = [];
            const foundPrice = 10;

            client.connect({}, () => {
                this.setState({
                    stompClient: client
                });

                client.subscribe('/topic/orders', (message) => {
                    JSON.parse(message.body).map((order) => {
                        const element = (
                            <ListGroup className="order">
                                <ListGroup.Item style={{"borderBottom":"none!important"}} className="order-view order-list-item">
                                    <div className="order-view-info">
                                        <h4 style={{"font-size":"1rem", "color":"white"}} className="order-view-title">196.36 RUB</h4>
                                        <p className="order-view-text">Price for 1 {order.asset.alias}</p>
                                    </div>
                                    <Button className="p2p-deals-btn">Sell</Button>
                                </ListGroup.Item>
                                <ListGroup.Item style={{"borderBottom":"none!important"}} className="order-view order-list-item">
                                    <div className="order-view-owner-info">
                                        <div className="order-view-info">
                                            <h6 style={{"display":"block", "color":"white"}} className="order-view-title">{order.user.name}</h6>
                                            <h6 style={{"display":"block"}} className="order-view-title">Sum</h6>
                                            <h6 style={{"display":"block"}} className="order-view-title">Limits</h6>
                                            <h6 style={{"display":"block"}} className="order-view-title">Payment methods</h6>
                                        </div>
                                        <div style={{"margin-left":"1rem"}} className="order-view-info">
                                            <h6 style={{"display":"block", "color":"white"}} className="order-view-text">Deals: {order.user.deals} · {order.user.deals/100*order.user.completedDeals}%</h6>
                                            <h6 style={{"display":"block"}} className="order-view-text">{order.assetAmount} {order.asset.alias}</h6>
                                            <h6 style={{"display":"block"}} className="order-view-text">10 000 - 100 000 {order.currency}</h6>
                                            <h6 style={{"display":"block"}} className="order-view-text">Some banks names</h6>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </ListGroup.Item>
                            </ListGroup>
                        )
                        let el = React.createElement('div', null, element);
                        elements.push(el)
                    });
                    root.render(elements);
                });
            });
        }
        
        connectToWebSocket();
        
        this.disconnectWebSocket = () => {
            if (this.state.stompClient) {
                this.state.stompClient.disconnect()
            }
        }
    }
    
    componentWillUnmount() {
        this.disconnectWebSocket();
    }
    
    sendMessage = () => {
        const user = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("user"));
        if (this.state.stompClient) {
            this.state.stompClient.send('/app/get-orders', {}, JSON.stringify({'orderType':'BUY', 'currency':'AED', 'assetAlias':'BTC', 'bankNames':['some-bank']}));
        }
    }

    render() {
        const { isLoggedIn } = this.props;
        const { order } = this.state;
        this.sendMessage()
        
        return(
            <div>
                <div id="p2p-body" className="p2p-body">
                    <ListGroup id="orders-list" className="orders-list">

                    </ListGroup>
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```